# Angular 2 how to bind check property of radiobutton to boolean attribute of component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular

How do I bind the checked property of radiobutton to boolean variable of Component class? What I desire, that radiobutton in template will be checked by default if the boolean flag is set.

I tried `<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="isSelected()">` but it throws template syntax error

```
platform-browser.umd.js:962EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 13 in [isSelected()=$event] in ChoiceComponent@5:6 ("
                    (change)="select()"
      required
      [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="isSelected()"> {{choice.text}}</label>
    </div>
    "): ChoiceComponent@5:6
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="isSelected()"` is invalid. You can't two-way bind to a function. What is the intention of your code? How does `isSelected()` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Radio isn't well supported yet. See also [Angular 2 forms; ngFormControl for radio and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407881/angular-2-forms-ngformcontrol-for-radio-and-select/37407932#37407932)

Until this is fixed you can try something like

```
<input type="radio" [ngModel]="{selected: model.sex == 'male'}" (ngModelChange)="model.sex='male'"  name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
```

See also [How to bind to radio buttons in angular2 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653175/how-to-bind-to-radio-buttons-in-angular2-beta-6/35653911#35653911)